# can I add a custom SSRS e-mail subscription that forces the "TO" address

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssrs, ssrs-2008

I would like to know if it is possible to add a custom delivery *extension(?)* in SSRS that will enable me to force a value into the "TO" address for particular subscriptions?

Big picture: I am exploring ways to schedule reports that would only permit them to be sent to a specific email address.

**EDIT:** Somewhat related, I would also like to know if I can create a second e-mail delivery extension without having do any programming.  i.e. I would copy the extension details from RSReportServer.config for the "Report Server Email", give it a new name, and change a single configuration value.

**SECOND EDIT:** In the hopes of getting some additional input and ideas, the big BIG picture is I want to create a method to create an SSRS subscription that would guarantee the recipient is a particular e-mail address.  This method should be usable by all users, but even knowing how to let one user might be workable.  Subscriptions to other e-mail addresses must still be permitted.

Answer (score 1):

What version of SQL Server/SSRS are you using? If you have SQL Server Enterprise then you can use Data Driven Subscriptions which allows you to use a query to define the various subscription delivery parameters such as To, CC, Subject etc.

Answer (score 0):

Struggling to understand the concept of this. Why would I as a user wish to subscribe to a report and have the subscription go to myself as well as a specific mailbox which I wouldn't know who or what the purpose is for this?

Is this to provide a copy of the delivered subscription content to a generic mailbox for monitoring purposes?

UPDATE:
I think you would need to create a custom asp page to deal with subscriptions rather than the report manager in order to achieve this. You could limit what values the user can specify when setting up a subscription.

Alternatively you could use a stored procedure/trigger to change the values of the to, CC, or bcc fields to your default mailbox after the subscription has been setup, though this may be confusing for users.

Even if this was achieved I presume all users will require access to this generic mailbox? What would prevent them from forwarding the email to another mailbox or saving the attachment to allow it to be transferred.